# jQuery nextUntil attribute is less then or equal to value

Tags: javascript, jquery, nextuntil

I have the following which works OK, but I need adapt it so that it compares the data-folder-level against being less than or greater to.

```
$elem.nextUntil( $("li[data-folder-level="+level+"]"), "li" ).remove();
```

I tried this...

```
$elem.nextUntil( $("li[data-folder-level<="+level+"]"), "li" ).remove();
```

But that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Example html

```
<li data-folder-level="0"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="1"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="1"><a href="#">CLICK ME!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="2"><a href="#">Will be removed...</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="2"><a href="#">Will be removed...</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="2"><a href="#">Will be removed...</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="3"><a href="#">Will be removed...</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="0"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="0"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="1"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="0"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="0"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="1"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="1"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="1"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="2"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="2"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
<li data-folder-level="2"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
```

So clicking on the 3rd in the list would remove the next 4 list items.

Comment: Try `filter` to filter data

Comment: jQuery doesn't have an `<=` attribute selector. Can you post up your HTML so we can see how to solve this.

Comment: @Tushar... I took your advice, but can't really credit you unless you post it as an answer!

Comment: How the elements should be removed? this-level + 1 or `level <= thislevel+1`

Comment: In the example shown, the subsequent 4 elements (with a folder-level greater than 1) should be removed - stopping when it reaches an element with a folder-level less than or equal to 1.

Comment: @Tom take a look at the answer

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) expects either a selector or an element as the first argument.

However, since jQuery 1.7, functions seem to work too. So you can use

```js
$elem.nextUntil(function () {
  return $(this).attr("data-folder-level") <= level;
}, "li").remove();
```

```js
$("ol").on("click", "li", function () {
  var level = +$(this).attr("data-folder-level");
  $(this).nextUntil(function () {
    return $(this).attr("data-folder-level") <= level;
  }, "li").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li data-folder-level="0"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="1"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="1"><a href="#">CLICK ME!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="2"><a href="#">Will be removed...</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="2"><a href="#">Will be removed...</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="2"><a href="#">Will be removed...</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="3"><a href="#">Will be removed...</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="0"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="0"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="1"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="0"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="0"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="1"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="1"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="1"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="2"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="2"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
  <li data-folder-level="2"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: How come this isn't documented?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any `<=` data-attribute selector, but you can use jQuery `nextUntil` and `filter` methods in order to check your sequent elements data-attribute and act accordingly.

Code:

```
$("li").click(function () {
    var $elem = $(this);
    var level = $(this).attr("data-folder-level");
    $elem.nextUntil().filter(function () {
        return $(this).attr("data-folder-level") > level;
    }).remove();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x0Lwvhc3/

### EDIT

Since you want to limit the deletion on the depth change you can use `each` and if a change is found stop it using `return false`.

Code:

```
$("li").click(function () {
    var $elem = $(this);
    var level = $(this).attr("data-folder-level");
    $elem.nextUntil().each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("data-folder-level") <= level) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/91jL1j6t/

Comment: You can safely remove `var $elem = $(this);` as it is not required to cache context here

Comment: Inside `filter` use only `return parseInt($(this).attr("data-folder-level")) <= level`

Comment: This removes more than the 4 subsequent elements.